# Android Studio Build Failed - Compiling local project errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, libraries

A few months ago, I decided to take some custom methods and classes that I was using in more than one project and put them in their own project called "FarmSoftLibraries" that all of my projects could reference.  This allowed me to make changes or additions once.  It has been working very well up until yesterday (8/23/2015) when i started getting an odd error on a new method that Gradle could not find.  However Android Studio had no problem finding this method.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167734/cannot-find-symbol-method-for-custom-static-class-method. However older, non-new methods continued to work.

Today the entire build system stopped working and I'm getting hundreds of Gradle errors saying that packages and methods in FarmSoftLibraries do not exist.  Still, Android Studio has no problem locating these.

```
D:\Scott\Android\Studio\SpellingTutor\app\src\main\java\com\farmsoft\spellingtutor\Learn.java:12: error: package com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils does not exist
import com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils.FarmUtils;
                                           ^
D:\Scott\Android\Studio\SpellingTutor\app\src\main\java\com\farmsoft\spellingtutor\Learn.java:14: error: package com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils does not exist
import com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils.Logg;
                                           ^
D:\Scott\Android\Studio\SpellingTutor\app\src\main\java\com\farmsoft\spellingtutor\utils\KeyValueDB.java:6: error: package com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils does not exist
import com.farmsoft.farmsoftlibraries.Utils.CsvUtil;

etc. etc. etc...
```

I want to stress that I've changed *NOTHING* in the gradle files.  I have been upgrading Android Studio on the Canary path - I'm on 1.4 Preview 3 now.  When this issue began I was on 1.4 Preview 2.  I have no idea if this is related to this version of Studio.

My gradle scripts:
**project settings.gradle:**

```
include ':app'

include ':farmsoftlibs'
project(':farmsoftlibs').projectDir = new File('../FarmSoftLibraries/app')
```

**app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.farmsoft.spellingtutor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.15"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile project(':farmsoftlibs')
}
```

**farmsoftlibs build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0'
}
```

I do want to admit I pretty much am ignorant about gradle - I follow the instructions for how to set it up in Android Studio, but I really don't know what I'm doing and have gotten lost in the Gradle documentation I tried to read.  So this is incredibly frustrating and more so knowing that this is probably due to some stupid mistake I've made out of ignorance.

EDIT:
This seems to have something to do with ProGuard - if I change the library's release settings to say minifyEnabled false, then the error goes away... for now.  I'd like to know why.

Comment: You don't need to add `compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')` because already have `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Thanks - good to know!

Comment: So, have you fixed the problem yet?

Comment: i dunno where to put this. If the build system is built from dumb parts, then the complexity is x from these dumb parts, and sure we can always use our brains to overcome it. Now, if the build system is built from intelligent parts, and sooner or later it will fail in one way or another, then the resulting complexity is x^2. And then, we find ourselves wrestling with the dragon...I'll stick with the dumb parts...